# Erro ao buscar relatório do Banco Central

Tags: r, url, libcurl

As funções para pegar as Expectativas do Banco Central do Relatório Focus estão apresentado o seguinte erro:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer"
```

***Exemplo do próprio pdf do Cran:***

```
library(rbcb)

indic <- c("Balanço de Pagamentos", "Fiscal")
end_date <- "2018-01-31"
x <- get_annual_market_expectations(indic, end_date = end_date, `$top` = 10)

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Alguem sabe o que esta acontecendo?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_4.7.1               ECharts2Shiny_0.2.13       flexdashboard_0.5.1.1      shinyWidgets_0.4.3         shinyjs_1.0               
 [6] shinydashboard_0.7.0       shiny_1.1.0                lazyeval_0.2.1             quantmod_0.4-13            TTR_0.23-3                
[11] qdapTools_1.3.3            mailR_0.4.1                bizdays_1.0.6              RODBC_1.3-15               devtools_1.13.6           
[16] PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.2 xts_0.11-0                 zoo_1.8-3                  timeDate_3043.102          lubridate_1.7.4           
[21] XLConnect_0.2-15           XLConnectJars_0.2-15       xtable_1.8-2               xlsxjars_0.6.1             rJava_0.9-10              
[26] xlsx_0.6.1                 openxlsx_4.1.0             readxl_1.1.0               RColorBrewer_1.1-2         png_0.1-7                 
[31] stringr_1.3.1              ggrepel_0.8.0              labeling_0.3               RGraphics_2.0-14           gcookbook_1.0             
[36] gridExtra_2.3              gridGraphics_0.3-0         gridBase_0.4-7             showtext_0.5-1             showtextdb_2.0            
[41] sysfonts_0.7.2             extrafontdb_1.0            extrafont_0.17             ggplot2_3.0.0              gtable_0.2.0              
[46] magrittr_1.5               dplyr_0.7.6                rbcb_0.1.5                

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-6      httr_1.3.1        rprojroot_1.3-2   backports_1.1.2   tools_3.5.1       R6_2.2.2          colorspace_1.3-2 
 [8] withr_2.1.2       tidyselect_0.2.4  curl_3.2          compiler_3.5.1    chron_2.3-52      xml2_1.2.0        scales_0.5.0     
[15] quadprog_1.5-5    digest_0.6.15     rmarkdown_1.10    R.utils_2.6.0     pkgconfig_2.0.1   htmltools_0.3.6   htmlwidgets_1.2.1
[22] rlang_0.2.1       rstudioapi_0.7    bindr_0.1.1       jsonlite_1.5      zip_1.0.0         R.oo_1.22.0       RCurl_1.95-4.11  
[29] Rcpp_0.12.17      munsell_0.5.0     R.methodsS3_1.7.1 stringi_1.1.7     yaml_2.1.19       plyr_1.8.4        promises_1.0.1   
[36] crayon_1.3.4      lattice_0.20-35   knitr_1.20        pillar_1.3.0      glue_1.2.0        evaluate_0.11     data.table_1.11.4
[43] httpuv_1.4.4.2    Rttf2pt1_1.3.7    cellranger_1.1.0  tidyr_0.8.1       purrr_0.2.5       assertthat_0.2.0  mime_0.5         
[50] later_0.7.3       viridisLite_0.3.0 tibble_1.4.2      memoise_1.1.0     bindrcpp_0.2.2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir o erro. Comigo está tudo bem, corre sem problemas.

Comment: Poxa, reproduzi em 2 computadores e obtive o mesmo erro. Vou tentar num terceiro

Comment: Assim como o Rui, rodei este exato código e não consegui reproduzir o erro. Faça o seguinte: execute o comando `sessionInfo()` e edite a pergunta com o output recebido. Talvez isto nos dê uma luz para encontrar a solução para o teu problema.

Comment: Editei com o output do sessionInfo()

Comment: Talvez haja um ficheiro .RData a estragar as coisas. Veja se há um ficheiro chamado .RData (isto é o nome completo do ficheiro, não é só a extensão) e se houver, remova-o e depois reinicie o R ou RStudio.

Comment: Resposta do próprio criador do pacote 'rbcb':

"Oi Rafael estou vendo isso. No meu ambiente as solicitações funcionam, mas outros usuários tem reportado problemas. E parece que não é apenas configuração de proxy. Na próxima semana deve sair um novo release com correções."